# XPath query foreach

Tags: php, xml, xpath

```
$table = $PageXpath->query('//table[10]'); 
$data['tr'] = $table->item(0)->nodeValue;
print_r($data);
```

Above works. It gives the the text of everything in that table.

However, it does not give me the `tr` and `td` html mark up. I need all of the `TR` elements, marked up. That way I can start dissecting them and passing them each in to a variable.

I need to target that specific table, then do a for each `TR`, do X with the first `<td>` then Y with the second `<td>` then Z with the third `<td>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nodeValue` of a node does not contain any tags - it is the result of the concatenation of all `DOMText` nodes within it.

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
// $Dom is the original DOMDocument object used when creating $PageXpath

$table = $PageXpath->query('//table[10]')->item(0);
$xml = $Dom->saveXML($table);
print_r($xml);
```

Be aware that most HTML isn't valid XML - using `DOMDocument` and `XPath` to parse HTML is very unreliable.

Comment: What are my other options? I am building a scraper to scrape a site. I thought it was about the only option I had.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Comment: George, I am new to stack overflow. I tried to help people in several categories but I can't post more then two links, and post once per three minutes. How do I get reputation built up?

Comment: As you contribute more to the SO community, you'll be rewarded with more privileges. Did that link help?